# nguniversal express-engine request nullinjector

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am successfully running an angular universal application with `@nguniversal/express-engine`. The part I can't get working is the injection of the node/express `req` object in the angular application. Following along the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine) does not fix the problem for me. The error is

> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken REQUEST!

On the server I setup the express-engine with the following excerpt

```js
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory, // Give it a module to bootstrap,
  providers: [ provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP) ]
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));
```

and render the index file with (1)

```js
app.get('*', (req: Request, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});
```

The injection into the app-component looks like

```js
constructor (
  @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request
) {}
```

while the `REQUEST` is imported from *@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens*. I've also tested the addition of the following entry in the rendering part (1), but it doesn't work either.

```
providers: [ { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req } ]
```

Also tried to inject with the `@Optional()` decorator and use `PLATFORM_ID` to check if the platform is `server`, the request object is not injected and `null`.
Do you have got any suggestions how to successfully access the `req` object in angular itself?

Comment: do you get error in browser or in node logs?

Comment: the error appears in the browser

Comment: You can't access `REQUEST` in browser, it is server side object passed from `expressjs` to `ng-universal`. So in the worst case your code should do something like `if (isServerPlatform(this.platformId)) { /* use req */ }` and also annotate `@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) req`. Then when in browser, your application won't look at `Request`, while when rendered on server side, will.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `REQUEST` in browser, it is server side object passed from `expressjs` to `ng-universal`. So in the worst case your code should do something like

```
constructor(
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
  @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request
) {
    doSomethingWithRequestIfServer();
}

someOtherMethod() {
    doSomethingWithRequestIfServer();
}

doSomethingWithRequestIfServer() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        // should see this in stdout of node process, or wherever node logs
        console.log('rendering server side for request:', req);
        /* use req */
    } else {
        // browser console should print null
        console.log('working browser side, request should be null', req);
    }
}
```

Then when in browser, your application won't look at Request, while when rendered on server side, will. I.e. it is like, your server side rendering will run your angular application **once**, as the result of this rendering HTML will be sent to browser. Then browser will bootstrap Angular application again and **pick up** from where server rendering is complete.

In the best case, to avoid `if`s and platform checks, I would suggest to layout your application so that your server side code is only provided on server side, and browser side code provided in browser. This will definitely require more code, but will be more straight forward from maintenance perspective.
(quick monkey typing below)

Common interface declaration

```
// common.ts
export abstract class MyServiceBase {
  abstract doSomething(): void;
}

// if implementations of service will be provided only in Angular implementation, InjectionToken can be used.
export const MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<MyServiceBase>('MY_SERVICE');
// otherwise, if server side implementation will be injected by from node process, then should be string only. (For alternative illustrated below in the end).
// export const MY_SERVICE = 'MY_SERVICE';
```

Common application component that should be rendered both on server and browser.

```
// app.component.ts
@Component({
  // skipped
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) myService: MyServiceBase) {
    myService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Common application code that is applicable for both server and browser side.

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

// app-browser.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceForBrowser extends MyServiceBase {
  constructor() {
    console.log('MyService browser implementation');
  }

  doSomthing(): void {
    // do something meaningful in browser 
  }
}
```

Bootstrap this, instead of default `AppModule` to separate implementation provisioning.

```
// app-browser.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
  providers: [{provide: MY_SERVICE, useClass: MyServiceForBrowser}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppBrowserModule {
}
```

**Server side from angular application**
If you can implement server side functionality straight away in Angular application, then.

```
// app-server.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceForServer extends MyServiceBase {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request) {
    console.log('MyService server implementation');
  }

  doSomthing(): void {
    // do something meaningful on server
    console.log('request is', this.request);
  }
}
```

Server side module to bootstrap from `ngExpressEngine`.

```
// app-server.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
  providers: [{provide: MY_SERVICE, useClass: MyServiceForServer}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**Alternative server side from server**

As alternative, `MyServiceForServer` can be even provided from server code. In this case, no need to provide implementation within angular implementation:

```
// app-server.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Instead, write it as normal server side code:

```
export class MyServiceForServer extends MyService {
  constructor(private request) {
    console.log('MyService server implementation');
  }

  doSomthing(): void {
    // do something meaningful on server
    console.log('request is', this.request);
  }
}
```

And inject as `external` value:

```
app.get('*', (req: Request, res) => {
  // construct the server side service instance
  const myService = new MyServiceForServer(req);
  // render server side with service instance provided
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), {
    providers: [{provide: MY_SERVICE, useValue: myService}],
    req
  });
});
```

In this case, make sure that your `MY_SERVICE` token is plain string, and not `InjectionToken` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. This does not fix my problem and I am familiar with the usage of `isPlatformServer` and `isPlatformBrowser`, but I can not successfully access the request object. Upvoted, but I can't accept it yet. Maybe it is related to the `AppServerModuleNgFactory` because its static?

Comment: The illustration gives you idea that, `request` object is not available in browser, because it happens only within server within expressjs. So you should not expect for existence of it in browser. And since you are complaining on error in browser as per you comment, then the answer explains you why. Remember, that request is user browser `GET` request to server. This `GET` request is processed by server, and response is plain `HTML` with artifacts like JavaScript etc. Then this response triggers angular application to start in browser. What req obj are you expecting to access within browser?

Comment: The other way, to make it clear, if you really want your request object in browser, then you have to serialize it and pass it within the response to browser (within header, cookie, TransferState etc). Then you can deserialize it in browser and access it accordingly. This way generally not the thing you are looking for. Just keep in mind that if you want to do SSR, then your angular application will run 2 times. Once on server and then in browser.

Answer (score -2):

Set the version in the package.json:

```
"@types/express": "^4.17.4",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
```